# Проблема смены окон с использованием PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, qt-designer

Пишу программу, которая заключается в небольшой тестовой системе. 
Я создал класс `Ui_Menu()`, который отвечает за приветственную страницу программы:

```
class Ui_Menu(object):
    def setupUi(self, Menu):
        Menu.setObjectName("Menu")
        Menu.resize(600, 600)
        Menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        Menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\\Users\\xomnr\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MyPython\\Infa Project\\screenshot-stock.adobe.com-2021.12.27-19_30_16\\"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Menu.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.menu_window = QtWidgets.QWidget(Menu)
        self.menu_window.setObjectName("menu_window")
        self.background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.background.setText("")
        self.background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\\Users\\xomnr\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MyPython\\Infa Project\\scale_1200.png"))
        self.background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.background.setObjectName("background")
        self.dark_background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.dark_background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.dark_background.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.dark_background.setText("")
        self.dark_background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.dark_background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.dark_background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.dark_background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.dark_background.setObjectName("dark_background")
        self.titul = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.titul.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(35, 70, 530, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.titul.setFont(font)
        self.titul.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);")
        self.titul.setObjectName("titul")
        self.titul_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.titul_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 220, 350, 180))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.titul_2.setFont(font)
        self.titul_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);")
        self.titul_2.setObjectName("titul_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.menu_window)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 500, 200, 70))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: white;\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border-color: black;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"border: 4 px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border-color: white;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        Menu.setCentralWidget(self.menu_window)

        self.retranslateUi(Menu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Menu)

    def retranslateUi(self, Menu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Menu.setWindowTitle(_translate("Menu", "Тест на знание флагов"))
        self.titul.setText(_translate("Menu", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Проект абвгд 10&quot;В&quot; по информатике</p><p align=\"center\">&quot;Тест на знание флагов&quot;</p></body></html>"))
        self.titul_2.setText(_translate("Menu", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Краткая инструкция</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Тест содержит 5 вопросов.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Тест оценивается по 5 бальной шкале.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Выберите вариант ответа и нажмите далее.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Чтобы начать прохождение жмите &quot;Начать&quot;!</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Menu", "Начать!"))
```

---

Далее, создавая первый вопрос (**`новое окно`** в программе) и я не смог реализовать метод (в коде она имеет название `open_question()`) при использовании которого, нажимая на кнопку **`Начать`** (`pushButton` из класса `Ui_Menu`) окно приветствия закрывается, а новое появляется.

Заранее спасибо.

```
from sys import argv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PIL import Image

class Ui_Menu(object):
    def setupUi(self, Menu):
        Menu.setObjectName("Menu")
        Menu.resize(600, 600)
        Menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        Menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\\Users\\xomnr\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MyPython\\Infa Project\\screenshot-stock.adobe.com-2021.12.27-19_30_16\\"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Menu.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.menu_window = QtWidgets.QWidget(Menu)
        self.menu_window.setObjectName("menu_window")
        self.background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.background.setText("")
        self.background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\\Users\\xomnr\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MyPython\\Infa Project\\scale_1200.png"))
        self.background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.background.setObjectName("background")
        self.dark_background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.dark_background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.dark_background.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.dark_background.setText("")
        self.dark_background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.dark_background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.dark_background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.dark_background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.dark_background.setObjectName("dark_background")
        self.titul = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.titul.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(35, 70, 530, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.titul.setFont(font)
        self.titul.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);")
        self.titul.setObjectName("titul")
        self.titul_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.titul_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 220, 350, 180))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.titul_2.setFont(font)
        self.titul_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);")
        self.titul_2.setObjectName("titul_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.menu_window)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 500, 200, 70))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: white;\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border-color: black;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"border: 4 px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border-color: white;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        Menu.setCentralWidget(self.menu_window)

        self.retranslateUi(Menu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Menu)

    def retranslateUi(self, Menu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Menu.setWindowTitle(_translate("Menu", "Тест на знание флагов"))
        self.titul.setText(_translate("Menu", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Проект абвгд 10&quot;В&quot; по информатике</p><p align=\"center\">&quot;Тест на знание флагов&quot;</p></body></html>"))
        self.titul_2.setText(_translate("Menu", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Краткая инструкция</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Тест содержит 5 вопросов.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Тест оценивается по 5 бальной шкале.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Выберите вариант ответа и нажмите далее.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Чтобы начать прохождение жмите &quot;Начать&quot;!</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Menu", "Начать!"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_question)

    def open_question(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.menu_window)
        app.close()
        
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        next = First_Question()
        next.setupUi(MainWindow)
        # self.menu_window.close()
        MainWindow.show()


class First_Question(object):
    def setupUi(self, Window):
        Window.setObjectName("First_Question")
        Window.resize(300, 300)
        Window.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        Window.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\\Users\\xomnr\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MyPython\\Infa Project\\screenshot-stock.adobe.com-2021.12.27-19_30_16\\"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Window.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.question_1_window = QtWidgets.QWidget(Window)
        self.question_1_window.setObjectName("first_question_window")
        self.background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.question_1_window)
        self.background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.background.setText("")
        self.background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\\Users\\xomnr\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MyPython\\Infa Project\\scale_1200.png"))
        self.background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.background.setObjectName("background")
        self.dark_background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.question_1_window)
        self.dark_background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.dark_background.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.dark_background.setText("")
        self.dark_background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.dark_background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.dark_background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.dark_background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.dark_background.setObjectName("dark_background")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Menu()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никогда не изменяйте код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, НИКОГДА.

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

**main.py**

```
from sys import argv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# ???from PIL import Image

class Ui_Menu(object):
    def setupUi(self, Menu):
        Menu.setObjectName("Menu")
        Menu.resize(600, 600)
        Menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        Menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
# !                                   vvvvvv
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Menu.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.menu_window = QtWidgets.QWidget(Menu)
        self.menu_window.setObjectName("menu_window")
        self.background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.background.setText("")
        self.background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
# !                                              vvvvvv         
        self.background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"))
        
        self.background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.background.setObjectName("background")
        self.dark_background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.dark_background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.dark_background.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.dark_background.setText("")
        self.dark_background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.dark_background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.dark_background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.dark_background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.dark_background.setObjectName("dark_background")
        self.titul = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.titul.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(35, 70, 530, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.titul.setFont(font)
        self.titul.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);")
        self.titul.setObjectName("titul")
        self.titul_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.menu_window)
        self.titul_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 220, 350, 180))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.titul_2.setFont(font)
        self.titul_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);")
        self.titul_2.setObjectName("titul_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.menu_window)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 500, 200, 70))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Neo Sans Pro Ultra")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: white;\n"
"border: 4px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border-color: black;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"border: 4 px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 25%;\n"
"border-color: white;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        Menu.setCentralWidget(self.menu_window)

        self.retranslateUi(Menu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Menu)

    def retranslateUi(self, Menu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Menu.setWindowTitle(_translate("Menu", "Тест на знание флагов"))
        self.titul.setText(_translate("Menu", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Проект абвгд 10&quot;В&quot; по информатике</p><p align=\"center\">&quot;Тест на знание флагов&quot;</p></body></html>"))
        self.titul_2.setText(_translate("Menu", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Краткая инструкция</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Тест содержит 5 вопросов.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Тест оценивается по 5 бальной шкале.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Выберите вариант ответа и нажмите далее.</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:400;\">Чтобы начать прохождение жмите &quot;Начать&quot;!</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Menu", "Начать!"))


class First_Question(object):
    def setupUi(self, Window):
        Window.setObjectName("First_Question")
        Window.resize(300, 300)
        Window.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        Window.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Window.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.question_1_window = QtWidgets.QWidget(Window)
        self.question_1_window.setObjectName("first_question_window")
        self.background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.question_1_window)
        
#        self.background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 600))
        self.background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 300))
        
        self.background.setText("")
        self.background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
# !                                              vvvvvvvv  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
        self.background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena.jpg").scaled(300, 300))
        
        self.background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.background.setObjectName("background")
        self.dark_background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.question_1_window)
        self.dark_background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 300))
        self.dark_background.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.dark_background.setText("")
        self.dark_background.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.dark_background.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.dark_background.setWordWrap(False)
        self.dark_background.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.dark_background.setObjectName("dark_background")
# !!!        
        Window.setCentralWidget(self.question_1_window)                    # +++


class FirstQuestion(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, First_Question):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstQuestion, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Menu):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_question)
        
        self.firstQuestion = FirstQuestion()

    def open_question(self):
        self.firstQuestion.show()
        self.hide()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ArtyomkaProgger что не так?